# Why the 'it' in Entity Framework and EntityDataSource examples?

Tags: entity-framework

Dumb question I'm sure, but why does Entity Framework EntityDataSource object require the where clause to contain '**it**' as the first part of the object selector?

The documentation for the where clause (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488531.aspx) states that the string is passed directly to the ObjectQuery(T), so I should be able to pass in (for example) "**x**.OnlineOrderFlag = TRUE" where x is anything that makes sense in a predicate, however the clause only works if I pass in "**it**.OnlineOrderFlag = TRUE"

All of the Microsoft examples use 'it' so what am I missing?

Steve Davies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like "it" is just an implicit parameter name. In query expressions this is provided by the range variable, but you don't specify the parameter name in the call to `Where`, so it looks like it just uses "it" implicitly.

I agree that it's poorly documented though :(

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jon, using 'it' feels like writing beginner code ... "_myControl = new Control" etc  oh well!   Steve

Comment: I think this goes with the whole Entity Framework.  I think I will go google for that "Vote of No Confidence" from the Alt.Net guys. :)